# Pivot in SQL is breaking on spaces

Tags: sql-server, replace, pivot

I am running a query to analyse some user properties in a couple of joined tables, and it's working fine, expect that my headers are being split on a space due to their value in the database.

This is the query I'm running:

```
DECLARE       @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
              @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select        @PivotColumns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Property_key) 
              from propertyentry where PROPERTY_KEY like 'jira.meta%'
                     and property_key not like '% %' -- removes tables with spaces in name, else won't pivot
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
              ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, user_name, first_name, last_name, ' +  @PivotColumns + ' from 
             (      
                                  select 
                                  --ps.id, cu.user_name, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, pe.property_key, cast(ps.propertyvalue as varchar(max)) as PV
                                  cu.user_name, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, ps.id, cast(ps.propertyvalue as varchar(max)) as PV, pe.property_key 
                                  from propertyentry pe 
                                  inner join propertystring ps
                                  on pe.id = ps.id 
                                  inner join external_entities ee
                                  on ee.ID = pe.entity_id
                                  inner join cwd_user cu
                                  on cu.user_name = ee.NAME
                                  ) x
            pivot 
            (
                           max(PV)
                           for property_key in (' + @PivotColumns + ')
            ) p 
                     order by 2,3,4'
execute(@query)
```

This outputs information like the following: (Can't format correctly as a table, sorry)

```
|| id || user_name || first_name || last_name || meta.Laptop || meta.Kit || meta.PC ||

| 27076 | 0@emeastore | UK Store | Hove | NULL | NULL | 1234 |

| 27076 | 0@emeastore | UK Store | Hove | NULL | SPARE |    NULL |

| 27076 | 0@emeastore | UK Store | Hove | YES | NULL |  NULL |
```

I'm going to handle "squishing" the rows into one, that's fine - the issue I have is that one of the tables has the field "meta.PC Asset" and as you can see, that's what's being split in the header.

Is there a way I can run the same query, but on the `property_key` replaces spaces with '_' at the time of select?

That would then give me the end results like this:

```
|| id || user_name || first_name || last_name || meta.Laptop || meta.Kit || meta.PC_Asset ||

| 27076 | 0@emeastore | UK Store | Hove | NULL | NULL | 1234 |

| 27076 | 0@emeastore | UK Store | Hove | NULL | SPARE |    NULL |

| 27076 | 0@emeastore | UK Store | Hove | YES | NULL |  NULL |
```

Comment: Try: `REPLACE(QUOTENAME(Property_key), ' ', '_')` or even `REPLACE(QUOTENAME(LTRIM(RTRIM(Property_key))), ' ', '_')` And share the value of `SELECT @PivotColumns`

Comment: I can not get the problem. You are quoting values, so you shouldn't have problems. Also `as you can see, that's what's being split in the header.` is not clear what you mean.

Comment: @lad2025 - `REPLACE(QUOTENAME(LTRIM(RTRIM(Property_key))), ' ', '_')` worked perfectly, and I also removed the `and property_key not like '% %'` - just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT @PivotColumns =
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(LTRIM(RTRIM(Property_key))), ' ', '_') 
       FROM propertyentry
       WHERE PROPERTY_KEY LIKE 'jira.meta%'    
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
          ,1,1,'');
```

to replace  with `_`